# Protractor-CucumberJS - Map Multiple Gherkin Statements to a Single Step Function

Tags: protractor, bdd, gherkin, cucumberjs

Can a common step function be mapped for multiple given-when-then statements? In Cucumber JS the step definitions are in the format

```
this.Given(/^I have the following for a particular test$/, function () {
        //code for the step
    });
```

For In C# version of BDD (Specflow), multiple gherkin statements can be bound to a single method. For e.g.

```
[Given(@"I have the following for a particular test")]
[Given(@"I have also the following for another test")]
public void GivenIHaveTheFollowingForAParticularTest()
{

}
```

Is there any mechanism to implement this in CucumberJS as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in cucumber.js using regex. For example:

```
this.Given(/^I have (?:the following for a particular|also the following for another)? test&/, function () {
    // code for step
});
```

Above regex will match both the statements so this step-definition will get called for both.

To test it have a look here: http://www.regextester.com/?fam=95418